# problems with installing fail2ban

Tags: linux, fail2ban

sorry for my bad english,
I'am not familiar with fail2ban , I need help in order to automaticly ban some ips who tries to connect on my server, I can't find the correct regex in order to let failban work correctly.

here is a part of my log

```
85.225.94.226 - - [03/Feb/2016:12:34:04 +0100] "GET /live/test/test/102.ts HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "VLC/2.1.0 LibVLC/2.2.1"
85.225.94.226 - - [03/Feb/2016:12:34:05 +0100] "GET /live/test/test/102.ts HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "VLC/2.1.0 LibVLC/2.2.1"
```

I want the correct failregex value in order to ban the ip 85.225.94.226
also iI want to inculde this part `"/test/test/"` in the failregex as well

I made it like this but it doesnt work

```
failregex = <HOST> - - [.*] "GET /live/test/test/.*
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
^<HOST>.*] "GET */test/test/*
```

You can check if the regex is working by running the following command:

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/yourlog.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/yourfilter.conf
```